# Load data from JavaScript into html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I have problems to load data from javascript into a html table.
So here is my java script code...

```
//success data
            $('#A').empty();
            $.each(data, function(index, aObj){
                //$('#A').append('<option value="' + aObj.id + '">'+aObj.note+'</option>');

                $('#A').append('<tr><td style="' + aObj.id + '">'+aObj.note+'</td style></tr>');
            });
```

The // option value works in a select box. But now I want to have the aObj.note into a table between the td style tags.

```
table class="table table-bordered table-striped" name="A" id="A">
                            thead>
                                tr>
                                   th class="">Note/th>
                                /tr>
                            /thead>
                            tbody>
                            @foreach($alleSpiele as $alleSpieleOutput)     
                                tr>
                                    td style="">/td style>
                                /tr>
                            @endforeach
                            /tbody>
                        /table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try like this:

```
var table = $("#table tbody");
$.each(data, function(idx, elem){
    table.append("<tr><td>"+elem.username+"</td><td>"+elem.name+"</td>   <td>"+elem.lastname+"</td></tr>");
});
```

More information can be found here:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have following solution...

```
//success data
            $('#A').empty();
            $.each(data, function(index, valueAusData){

                $('#myTable tr:last').after('<tr>')
                $('#myTable tr:last').after('<td>'+ valueAusData.note+'</td>')
                $('#myTable tr:last').after('<td>'+ valueAusData.note+'</td>')
                $('#myTable tr:last').after('</tr>')
            });
```

And here my table

```
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="myTable">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Note</th>
                    <th>Note Zwei</th>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I know that after is not the correct statement here. But with which statement I have to replace after that alle values are under the tr td in the html table?